# Disable Istanbul for Jest Debugging

Tags: node.js, jestjs, istanbul

I'm trying to debug some failing tests written in Jest. While I can do so, attaching the chrome debugger just fine I'm noticing that Istanbul has obviously been at work and is making my files much more difficult to work with.

Does anyone know if there's a way to disable Istanbul, or to somehow get Node to debug through the equivalent of a map file?

**EDIT**
Here is an example of a file I'm trying to debug. In source it's called `handlerFactory.js` but in chrome I end up debugging the `VM3376 handlerFactory.js` file when stepping in from my test function.

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
cov_6n2doqihv.s[10]++;

const insertCheckins = postgres => {
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  cov_6n2doqihv.f[2]++;
  cov_6n2doqihv.s[11]++;
  return (
    /**
     * Function to insert the records
     * @param  {Object} checkIns The check-in records
     * @return {Promise}
     */
    async checkIns => {
      /* istanbul ignore next */
      cov_6n2doqihv.f[3]++;
      cov_6n2doqihv.s[12]++;
      return Promise.all(checkIns.map(checkin => {
        /* istanbul ignore next */
        cov_6n2doqihv.f[4]++;
        cov_6n2doqihv.s[13]++;
        return insertRecord(postgres)(checkin);
      }));
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about the "equivalent of map file" ?

Comment: @Teneff I've added an example of the sort of code I'm seeing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Istanbul is disabled by default, it is probably enabled in the jest configuration either in `package.json` or `jest.config.js`

To disable it you can remove the `configuration` line

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "jest": {
-    "coverage": true
  }
}
```

or explicitly run `jest` without coverage

`jest --coverage=false`

To use Nodejs debugger in VSCode you can take a look at [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#debugging-in-vs-code) or try with [this `launch.json`](https://github.com/Teneff/jest-workshop/blob/master/.vscode/launch.json)

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I'll have a dig around and see if I can see where it's enabled. I looked around the docs and couldn't see anything about enabling/disabling.

Comment: @Ian `jest --showConfig` might give you an overview about the current configuration